# OpenFileDialog.FileName пустой после выбора файла

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Здрасте, начал учить C#, решил написать прогу типа блокнота.

```
namespace OnePap
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            return ofd;
        }

        private void  OpenFile(object sender, object e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog of = OpenFileDialog();
            of.Filter = "|*.txt";
            if ((bool)of.ShowDialog())
            {
                Writer.Text = File.ReadAllText(of.FileName); //После открытия файла, of.FileName пустой
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Для создания окна выбора файла использовал `OpenFileDialog`, но после выбора файла, `of.FileName` пустой.

[image: Фото ошибки]

Comment: у вас на картинке `of.FileName` пустой, вот и нельзя ничего открыть.

Comment: после открытия файла в него должно передаваться имя файла, но этого не происходит.

Comment: ну так может вы что то не так делаете? OpenFileDialog  - стандартный контрол, если он не передает имя файла, то вы наверное пытаетесь несушествующий файл открыть или еще какие не те кнопки нажимаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в фильтре, честно точно не понимаю как он влияет, но это работает :)

В общем нужно написать вместо:

```
of.Filter = "|*.txt";
```

Вот так:

```
of.Filter = "|*.txt|All|*.*";
```

Comment: или так `of.Filter = "текстовые файлы (.txt)|*.txt";`